# How to send the content of a line of the GridView to another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I have a `GridView`  with some `BoundFields` and one `Button` inside the grid.
I'd like to fire the `OnClick` event of the button to open a new window and also get the content of that whole line to edit it ... How Could I do that ?
I dont want to use `QueryString` and I think `Session`isn't the best way so is there an other safe way to do that ?

Obs: I get the content of my `GridView` from my `DataBase` using a `SqlDataSource` inside the `aspx` page. Its a little harder for me than for the most people because I used to programm on WebForms, it's the first time i'm working with web =\

Comment: It's better to tag your post instead of pointing that in your post.

Comment: Ohh , you mean the First Line ?

Comment: How about PostBackUrl and the selected index? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx

Comment: @Ghaleon See this if you are new to SO : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I'll read it right now ! I don't know If I could be clear. I'd like to do that only to `EDIT` one field of the gridview, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: The easiest is to use a single query-string parameter for the primary key value of the row. Then you just have to load the load the content from database on the details-page. That has also the advantage that you get the values at the last place. Otherwise a different user could have changed some values meanwhile.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What's better, `Session` or `Query-String` ?!

Comment: @ScottE I tried but no success =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using Sessions:

```
Session["login"].ToString() = TxtLogin.ToString();
```

and do retrieve the information:

```
TxtTeste.Text = Session["login"].ToString();
```